# How to make a character conditional at the frontend?

Tags: javascript

At the client side I have the following line:

```
<img data-tip={`${data.name}, ${data.function || ''}`} alt="img" src={data.avatar} />
```

But the comma between name and function I would only like to display if function has a value. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Function has a value? what does it mean

Comment: Proper HTML note: the `alt` attribute exists for a reason: use a real description (because that's going to get read out loud by screenreaders to people with visual disabilities or blindness) or don't add it at all. Don't ever use things like `img`.

Comment: Good point @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, I've removed it.
kinduser, it displays a tooltip at the front end.

Comment: What is data.function? And what does mean "if function has a value". Data object could have assigned function but it needs to be named, for example (data.functionName).

Comment: it should be fairly obvious that what is meant is that `function` is a truthy property on `data`. Not that it's an executable property that needs to be executed in order to get a return value.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans This is absolutely senseless. Why would he display a function declaration? Or just the name of that key is highly misleading.

Comment: No it isn't, you just forgot that `function` is also a normal English word and JS objects can use anything they like for property names. This is clearly a data object, and it's not too hard to imagine a data object such as ```data = { name: `herpetological`, function: `adjective`, complexity: 12 }```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with React, really, you're asking about how to compose a string in JS.

If the comma (and presumably, subsequent white space) only needs to be there when `data.function` exists, use a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator):

```
// template strings allow template strings inside of them:
const tipText = `${data.name}${data.function ? `, ${data.function}` : ``}`;
const description = `some description of what is in this image, or what it illustrates`;
const img = <img data-tip={tipText} alt={description} src={data.avatar} />
```

Or, without nesting strings:

```
const suffix = data.function ? `, ${data.function}` : ``;
const tipText = `${data.name}${suffix}`;
const description = `some description of what is in this image, or what it illustrates`;
const img = <img data-tip={tipText} alt={description} src={data.avatar} />
```

Note that `alt` attribute: either fill in a real description, or leave it off. Filling in a nonsense value is the worst you can do: that attribute gets read out loud by screen readers for people with visual disabilities.

Answer (score -1):

Here is my solution.

```js
`${data.name}${data.function ? ', ' + data.function : ''}`
```

or

```js
`${data.name}${data.function ? `, ${data.function}` : ''}`
```

Comment: don't use legacy string concatenation (using `+`) when you're also using template strings. Any half-decent linter will throw at least two errors at you over this code now. (one for using legacy concatenation, and one for mixing string composition patterns)